# How do I transmit a unicode character above 0xffff to a Windows (Possibly Win32?) Application?

Tags: windows, winapi, unicode, language-agnostic, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ as my test case, but I was also able to replicate the exact same behavior on a program I wrote that (indirectly) uses the Win32 API, so I'm trusting at this time that the behavior is specific to Windows, and not to the individual programs.

At any rate, I'm trying to use alt-codes to transmit unicode text to a program. Specifically, I'm using the "Alt Plus" method [described in the first point here](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm). For any and all alt-codes below `0xffff`, this method works perfectly fine. But the moment I try to transmit an alt-code above this threshold, the input only retains the last four digits I typed.

From notepad++ using UCS-2 Big Endian:

[image: Image showing received codepoints]

To generate this output, I used the following keystrokes:

```
[alt↓][numpad+][numpad1][numpad2][numpad3][numpad4][alt↑]
[alt↓][numpad+][numpad1][numpad2][numpad3][numpad5][alt↑]
[alt↓][numpad+][numpad1][numpad2][numpad3][numpad4][numpad5][alt↑]
```

Knowing that the first two bytes are encoding specific data, it's clear that the first two characters transmitted were successful and correct, but the third was truncated to only the last 2 bytes. Specifically, it did not try to perform a codepoint→UTF16 conversion; it simply dropped the higher bits.

I observed identical behavior on the program I wrote.

So my questions then are in two parts:

1. Is this a hard constraint of Windows (or at least the Win32 API), or is it possible to alter this behavior to split higher codepoints into multiple UTF-16 (or UTF-8) characters?
2. Is there a better solution for transmitting unicode to the application that doesn't involve writing a manual parser in the software itself?

To expand on that second point: In the program I wrote, I was able implement the intended functionality by discarding the "Text Handling" code and writing, by hand, a unicode parser in the "Key Handling" code which would, if the `[alt]` key were held down, save numpad inputs to an internal buffer and convert them to a codepoint when `[alt]` was released. I *can* use this as a solution if I must, but I'd like to know if there's a better solution, especially on the OS side of things, rather than a software solution.

Comment: How is this programming. You are trying to type?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's a programming issue because it involves working out how to receive Unicode codepoints from OS events. I don't see why that's unrelated to programming, or why it merits a snarky response.

Comment: Which version of Windows? I don't know if it makes a difference, but it might.

Comment: @MarkRansom I've tested using Windows 7 and Windows 10. Same results on both.

Comment: @Xirema: When I try your keystrokes in any editor on my Windows 7, I get very different results. Pressing the `+` key while holding down `Alt` does not work (Windows beeps, meaning the key is not allowed), and the resulting hex from the digit keystrokes produces `65 25 59 25 39 00`. Do you have some special software installed that enables `+` to be used?

Comment: @RemyLebeau In the link I provided, it indicated that using that method of alt-code entry may require a registry key edit first.

Comment: @Xirema: I didn't see that at first. When I applied it, `+` is now accepted and I get the same result as you (my editors use little endian, like Windows does): `34 12 35 12 45 23`. But even with `+` enabled, it seems the hex codes still cannot exceed `FFFF`, only the last 4 keys typed are used when `Alt` is released. So this would be to be a design issue at the OS layer (it probably only supports UCS-2 input and not UTF-16), so you won't be able to work around it using alt codes, you will have to use an IME or other alternative means of keyboard input.